# Install newer APK on older one that was compiled from different computers

Tags: android, delphi, apk, firemonkey

I have a Delphi app (not in the Play Store) that is out for a while, originally written in Delphi 10.3.

I have now switched computers and upgraded to Delphi 11.1 with a higher Android SDK as well.

When I try to install the updated APK on a device with an existing one, I can't install it without uninstalling the older version first.

Any way to deal with this without having to uninstall the older version?

Comment: Did use use the same key store? When switching you also need to use the same key store so you don't need to uninstall the previous verison.

Comment: You need to migrate the keystore used for signing the APK files from your old PC to your new one. Where the keystore is saved often bases on the project and used IDE. The only common place where it could be stored is in your home directory in the folder `.android`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work.

Delphi has his default Keystore when not compiling for the Play Store. The file is called `debug.keystore` it is located in `AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0`
When copying this file from old computer to the new one and rebuilding APK the new can overwrite the old APK with no erors.